# Optimizing a SQL query finding entries that do not exist in table

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have a log table that contains job status. One of the columns is job name. Sometimes a job will not run at all, and therefore there is no entry. My SQL determines which jobs are 'missing' from the log.

This query takes around 17 minutes, which is very long. I have plenty of other more complex ones (at least look more complex) that do not take this long.

How can this be optimized?

```
-- Display missing jobs. Thats jobs that are not in job log but should be
declare @startDate datetime, @endDate datetime
declare @rangeInHours int
set @rangeInHours = -24
set @endDate = '2012-01-17 12:00:01'
set @startDate = dateadd(hour, @rangeInHours, @endDate)

declare @myTable table( name nvarchar(50))
insert into @myTable values('Activity work')
-- There are another 100 entries like this one above to add all the expected jobs

-- this is my sql to find missing jobs
select distinct i.name from @myTable i
where not exists
 ( select 1 from job_log j
     where j.name = i.name 
       and j.start_date > @startDate and j.start_date < @endDate
  )
order by i.name asc
```

Been through a number of threads but could not find suitable answer, at least one I could understand and implement with my limited SQL.

Comment: Do you have proper indexes on `job_log`, specifically a covering index on `(name, start_date)`? Can you post the query plan?

Comment: How many records are in job_log?  The query looks sound, so like Lieven says, I think it'll be an index issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below, it might give you better performance than a nested select.

```
select distinct m.name
from @myTable m
left outer join job_log j on j.name = m.name and j.start_date > @startDate and j.start_date < @endDate
where j.name is null
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and my query went from 17 mins to 10 seconds ! Awesomeness ! Would also like to thank everyone else for the useful and very quick responses. Sorry, cant vote anyone up yet, or I would have.

Answer (score 1):

As with most SQL questions, the answer lies with your schema, not with your query. To check if a job with name @name and start_date between @start and @end exists then you **must** have an index on (name, start_date):

```
create index job_log_name_start on (name, start_date);
```

As a general rule, always post the exact definition of the tables involved when asking SQL question, including all indexes. What is the clustered index key for job_log? Time series are usually clustered by the time key, since most queries ask for time ranges, which would make your job_log table to be likely clustered by `start_date`.

For more fancy stuff, the general solution for answering 'this entry definitely doesn't exists?' is answered with [Bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), and I've seen SQL based implementation (eg. hash the `name` and the hour of the job).

Comment: Kind of what I asked in comments but `user1154526` probably already has left the building <g>. +1 on the Bloom filters reference.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have an index on `job_log.name`.

```
DECLARE @rangeInHours int = -24; 
DECLARE @endDate datetime = '2012-01-17 12:00:01';
DECLARE @startDate datetime = DATEADD(hour, @rangeInHours, @endDate);    
DECLARE @ExpectedJobs table(name nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO @ExpectedJobs values('Activity work'), ('foo'), ('bar');

SELECT      e.name AS MissingJob
FROM        @ExpectedJobs AS e
LEFT JOIN   job_log AS j ON j.name = e.name 
WHERE
    j.[name] IS NULL
AND j.start_date > @startDate 
AND j.start_date < @endDate
GROUP BY e.name
ORDER BY e.name;
```